# Htaccess issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file as follows

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /site/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}> !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

It works fine as a MVC however if when I type in a filename that exists e.g index.php and end it with a "/" e.g index.php/ - the browser gets confused and renders the data and styles wrong. and every link clicked with in then gets routed to 
"index.php/clicked-link.watever"

Can someone please explain why it does this and how to prevent this.

Comment: thats how the browser suppose to behave. you all ways have to update your links based on how you have your htaccess file setup.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses I will be testing them out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute urls eg:

```
  <a href="http://www.example.com/clicked-link.watever"
  <link type="text/css" src="http://www.example.com/css/style.css"
```

instead of relative urls eg:

```
  <a href="clicked-link.watever"
  <link type="text/css" src="/css/style.css"
```

an absolute url will point to a certain page or address and is not concerned with the relative location of the current page. if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of rules otherwise last rule is never executing since your first rule is catch all rule.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /site/ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}> !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```